Why does Vitess have/need workflows?
I've been reading through the docs, but the "workflow" concept/feature for vtctldclient is something that I'm having a bit of a challenge wrapping my head around.
With vtctldclient and its various sub-commands like Reshard , MoveTables, and others, they all use the the --workflow option. And with the getting started guide examples, it just uses that option without really explaining why it's used. The documentation doesn't really give a clear explanation either.
Also, I've gone through the getting started guide for the k8s operator and I noticed that commands like vtctldclient MoveTables create ... and vtctldclient vdiff create ... do not execute synchronously on the command line.
Would it be correct to say that, when you run these commands on the command line, they will get added to a "queue" (a "workflow queue"?) in the Vitess cluster, in the same order that they're executed so that Vitess will then also run these commands in that same order?
This way, for example, if there commands that need to retrieve data about a keyspace, like vdiff, Vitess will only run vdiff after the MoveTables command has completed execution.
Am I on the right track here?
So, here are a summary of my questions:

What are the purpose of "workflows" in the context vtctldclient?
Why is it needed?
What benifits does it offer beyond just making sure that vtctldclient commands have a chance at running sucessfully?

